# The definition of the distribution function of a n-dimensional normal distribution

Tags: probability

I just finished reading a chapter in my statistics book which covered multidimensional distributions. The last part of the chapter was about the normal distribution. The book gave me the following definition for the density function for the *n*-dimensional random variable $\mathbb{X} = (\mathbb{X_1},\mathbb{X_2},...,\mathbb{X_n})$:

$f_{\mathbb{X}}(x) = {{1 \over {(2\pi)^{n/2}|det C|}}exp(-(x-m)C^{-1}(x-m)^T)}$

Where $m$ is the expected value vector of $\mathbb{X}$ and $C$ is the covariance matrix of $\mathbb{X}$. I follow most of this, but there is one thing that puzzle me: The $T$ in $(x-m)^T$.

I've read through the text multiple times, but I can't seem to find an explanation to what this mysterious $T$ is. Could someone please explain what it is?

Comment: Here they are working with 'row vectors' $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and the $T$ 'makes' such a row vector a 'column vector'. It is more common to work with column vectors. A $T$ on a column vector will make it... Well, juest guess :-). It is the $T$ of *transposition*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It denotes transpose of the vector $(x-m)$. The transpose of a $m\times n$ matrix with $a_{ij}$ as the $(i,j)^{th}$ element, is a $n\times m$ matrix with $a_{ji}$ as the $(i,j)^{th}$ element.

Comment: I recognize this, although it was long lost in my memory. Thank you!